# Consulta se imprima en un solo td

Tags: php, sql

Tengo una tabla el cual refleja una compra realizada por un cliente o comprador, el cual tiene un identificador que seria el numero del pedido, esta refleja que pidió el cliente, pero me muestra en varios tds los datos del pedido use un group by pero no funciono ponerlos en un solo td
Esta la estructura de la tabla de donde tomo los datos :detalle
[image]Aqui estan los datos como se muestran en la tabla

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Y Asi se muestran en los td quiero organizarlos que se muestren  que se impriman todos los productos de un pedido en un solo td es decir los el pedido 15 imprimir en un solo td todos los productos que se genero en ese pedido

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```js
<div class="panel panel-info">
                               <div class="panel-heading text-center"><i class="fa fa-refresh fa-2x"></i><h3>Datos del  pedido</h3></div>
                              <div class="table-responsive">
                                  <table class="table table-bordered">
                                      <thead class="">
                                          <tr>
                                              <th class="text-center">#</th>
                                              <th class="text-center">Codigo del producto</th>
                                              <th class="text-center">Cliente</th>
                                              
                                              <th class="text-center">Cantidad de productos</th>
                                              
                                          </tr>
                                      </thead>
                                      <tbody>
                                          <?php
                                            $pedidoU=  ejecutarSQL::consultar("select * from detalle, producto,cliente");
                                            $upp=1;
                                            while($peU=mysql_fetch_array($pedidoU)){
                                                echo '
                                                    
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td>'.$peU['NumPedido'].'<input type="hidden" name="num-pedido" value="'.$peU['NumPedido'].'"></td>
                                                            <td>'.$peU['CodigoProd'].'-   '.$peU['NombreProd'].'</td>
                                                            <td>';
                                                                $conUs= ejecutarSQL::consultar("select * from cliente where NIT='".$peU['NIT']."'");
                                                                while($UsP=mysql_fetch_array($conUs)){
                                                                    echo $UsP['Nombre'];
                                                                }
                                                    echo   '<td>';
                                                                $conUs= ejecutarSQL::consultar("select Nombre,NumPedido,CodigoProd,CantidadProductos from detalle,cliente group by Nombre ");
                                                                while($UsP=mysql_fetch_array($conUs)){
                                                                    echo  $UsP['CantidadProductos'] ;
                                                                }'</td>
                                                            
                                                        </tr>
                                                      </form>
                                                    </div>
                                                    ';
                                                $upp=$upp+1;
                                            }
                                          ?>
                                      </tbody>
                                  </table>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: No se entiende bien qué es lo que quieres en un sólo `td`. ¿Todos los productos, o un `td` por cada producto? ¿De todos los pedidos del cliente, o de un pedido en específico del cliente? Por favor [edita la pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/101305/edit)  poniendo un ejemplo del tipo de salida que quieres.

Comment: un td por cada producto esta, creo que esta visible en las imágenes que coloque, lo que se requiere es que se impriman todos los productos de un pedido en un solo td es decir los el pedido 15 imprimir en un solo td todos los productos que se genero ese pedido...

Comment: Tampoco cuesta tanto explicar mejor lo que quieres. ¿Quieres algo así?: `Fila 1 - > Columna 1: NºPedido; Columna 2: 123-scsa, 21-zapatos shoes, ... Columna 3: Nombre del Cliente; Columna 4: Suma de la cantidad de productos`

Comment: Si he entendido bien, y por lo que muestran las imágenes estás en MySQL, puedes obtener los productos usando `GROUP_CONCAT`. Por ejemplo: `select Nombre,NumPedido,GROUP_CONCAT(CodigoProd SEPARATOR ',') productos,CantidadProductos from detalle,cliente group by NumPedido;` tendrás una columna llamada `productos` con todos los productos de ese pedido separados por coma.  Hay algunas cosas extrañas en tu código, como el hecho de enviar tres consultas (¡dos de ellas dentro de bucles!) ¿para obtener el resultado final?  y el no uso de `JOINS` para unir las tablas por sus claves primarias/foráneas.

Comment: si estoy usando Mysql y si la idea es esa pero no me da el resultado que es, mezcla todo en los td, es decir une el nombre del cliente, con el pedido y asi, este es el cod

Comment: echo   '<td>';
                                                                $conUs= ejecutarSQL::consultar("select Nombre,NumPedido,GROUP_CONCAT(CodigoProd SEPARATOR ','),CantidadProductos from detalle,cliente group by NumPedido; ");
                                                                while($UsP=mysql_fetch_array($conUs)){
                                                                 
                                                                    echo  $UsP['NumPedido'] ;
                                                                }'</td>

Comment: Bien, bien. Tú debes tener al menos 3 tablas: `clientes, articulos, detalle(¿pedidos?)`. ¿Es así?  ¿Cómo se relacionan esas tablas entre sí, por qué columnas? Esos son detalles importantes que faltan en la pregunta y en las consultas que tienes no veo que establezcas ningún tipo de relación entre las tablas. Intuyo que hay errores de diseño en tus tablas, por ejemplo en detalle, ¿repites `CodigoProd` por cada pedido que hacen? Eso debería ser un id de la tabla `articulos` no una columna del tipo `VARCHAR(30)`.

Comment: Las tablas son Clientes, Productos (el cual tiene como primaria CodProd) y detalles que es donde se envian los datos de la compra,el cual tiene como foranea el CodProd y tiene cantidad de productos y el numero del pedido

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intuyo que hay errores de diseño en tus datos, por ejemplo, haces al menos tres consultas para obtener datos que, con un diseño adecuado, se podrían obtener en una sola consulta.

Te muestro este diseño, con algunas pruebas de datos, por si te puede servir.

Es un diseño digamos *normal*  del tipo de aplicación que parece, intentas hacer.

Hay 4 tablas:

- `clientes`
- `productos`
- `pedidos`
- `detalles_pedidos`

Las tablas se relacionan de la siguiente manera:

- Tabla `pedidos` con tabla `clientes` mediante la llave `cliente_id`
- Tabla `pedidos` con tabla `productos` mediante la llave `producto_id`
- Tabla `detalles_pedidos` con tabla `pedidos` mediante la llave `pedido_id`

Es algo hecho rápido, más relaciones y refinamientos son posibles...

La siguiente consulta te traerá agrupados los datos por `pedido_id` y una columna llamada `productos` con los datos concatenados por coma `,`:

```
SELECT 
    cl.cliente_nom,  
    pe.pedido_id, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(pr.producto_nom SEPARATOR ',')productos, 
    pe.fecha
FROM detalles_pedidos_20170911 dp 
    INNER JOIN pedidos_20170911 pe ON dp.pedido_id=pe.pedido_id 
    INNER JOIN productos_20170911 pr ON dp.producto_id=pr.producto_id 
    INNER JOIN clientes_20170911 cl ON pe.cliente_id=cl.cliente_id
GROUP BY pe.pedido_id;
```

A esta consulta se pueden aplicar otros tipos de filtros, o traer más datos de cualquiera de las 4 tablas implicadas en ella.

### `Código:` <kbd>[VER DEMO EN REXTESTER](http://rextester.com/EQY74433)</kbd>

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS clientes_20170911 (
    cliente_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
    cliente_nom VARCHAR(70)
);


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS productos_20170911 (
    producto_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
    producto_nom VARCHAR(50),
    INDEX (producto_nom)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS pedidos_20170911 (
    pedido_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
    cliente_id INT,
    fecha DATETIME,
    INDEX (cliente_id,fecha),
    FOREIGN KEY (cliente_id) REFERENCES clientes_20170911(cliente_id)
    ON DELETE CASCADE


);


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS detalles_pedidos_20170911 (
    pedido_id INT, 
    producto_id INT,
    cantidad INT,
    INDEX (pedido_id,producto_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (pedido_id) REFERENCES pedidos_20170911(pedido_id)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
);



INSERT INTO clientes_20170911 (cliente_nom)
    VALUES ('Pedro'),('Santiago'),('Juan')
;


INSERT INTO productos_20170911 (producto_nom)
    VALUES 
        ('Zapatos Chinos no falsicados'),
        ('Mac Book Air 2013'),
        ('Producto 3'),
        ('Producto 4'),
        ('Producto 5')

;


INSERT INTO pedidos_20170911 (cliente_id, fecha)
    VALUES 
        (1,'2017-09-06'),
        (2,'2017-09-06'),
        (3,'2017-09-07'),
        (1,'2017-09-08')
;


INSERT INTO detalles_pedidos_20170911 (pedido_id, producto_id, cantidad)
    VALUES 
        (1,1,5),
        (1,3,2),
        (1,5,1),
        (2,2,1),
        (2,4,1),
        (3,1,1),    
        (3,2,2),
        (3,3,2),
        (4,2,1),
        (4,3,2),
        (4,4,3),
        (4,5,4)
;


SELECT 
    cl.cliente_nom,  
    pe.pedido_id, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(pr.producto_nom SEPARATOR ',')productos, 
    pe.fecha
FROM detalles_pedidos_20170911 dp 
    INNER JOIN pedidos_20170911 pe ON dp.pedido_id=pe.pedido_id 
    INNER JOIN productos_20170911 pr ON dp.producto_id=pr.producto_id 
    INNER JOIN clientes_20170911 cl ON pe.cliente_id=cl.cliente_id
GROUP BY pe.pedido_id;
```

#### `Resultado`

```
cliente_nom pedido_id   productos                                                    fecha
Pedro       1           Producto 5,Zapatos Chinos no falsicados,Producto 3           06.09.2017 00:00:00
Santiago    2           Mac Book Air 2013,Producto 4                                 06.09.2017 00:00:00
Juan        3           Producto 3,Zapatos Chinos no falsicados,Mac Book Air 2013    07.09.2017 00:00:00
Pedro       4           Producto 5,Producto 3,Producto 4,Mac Book Air 2013           08.09.2017 00:00:00
```